# Firebase Firestore writes only working on the first attempt of a fresh build

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I've been building an app with Firebase & React Native primarily using Firestore. I started to use Firestore and its been great, but for some reason when writing to Firestore, it is only working on the first attempt (when i remove the app, rebuild, and perform my write).

I tried to do the exact same thing except write to Firestore and everything works as expected.

I am also receiving no error!

Here is what I am doing:

```
export const addBrandProduct = (postObj) => {
  return () => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('brandProducts')
      .add(postObj)
      .then((docRef) => {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        Actions.categories();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      });
  };
};
```

For more of a reference, here is my component code that calls addBrandProduct()

```
  onUploadImages = () => {
    let photo =
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? this.state.images.map(img => img.uri.replace('file://', ''))
        : this.state.images.map(img => img.uri);

      photo.forEach((image, i) => {
      const sessionId = new Date().getTime();
      const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
      const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
      window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
      window.Blob = Blob;
      let uploadBlob = null;
      let mime = 'image/jpg';
      const imageRef = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref('brandProducts/')
        .child(`${this.props.userData.uid}`)
        .child(`${sessionId}-${i}`);

      fs.readFile(image, 'base64')
        .then(data => {
          return Blob.build(data, {type: `${mime};BASE64`});
        })
        .then(blob => {
          uploadBlob = blob;
          return imageRef.put(blob, {contentType: mime});
        })
        .then(() => {
          uploadBlob.close();
          return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        })
        .then(url => {
          //if this is the last uploaded image, post data to db
          if (i === this.state.images.length - 1) {
            const urls = {
              ...this.state.urls,
              [i]: url,
            };
            const postObj = {
              ...this.state.postObj,
              urls: urls,
            };
            this.props.addBrandProduct(postObj);
          } else {
            this.setState({
              urls: {
                ...this.state.urls,
                [i]: url,
              },
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  };
```

Basically, I am uploading a maximum of 3 images along with some data for it. In order to ensure I am uploading them all prior to adding the post data (writing to firestore) I am using a forEach and on the last upload, when it completes, I am calling the action to write the post data.

Comment: So you don't see any `Document writter...` but do you see any error like `Error adding document` ?

Comment: @farvilain I forgot to mention that, I don't receive any error at all which makes it worse!!

Comment: Argh... Please provide the component code that call `addBrandProduct`. The error should be there

Comment: @farvilain I just updated my question, hopefully i explained the code enough it could look a bit confusing - please let me know if I can clear anything up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edition*

Hum `addBrandProduct` is a function that create another function.
So when you call `this.props.addBrandProduct(postObj)` nothing is sent to firestore, you just create a new function that should be called.

Maybe you can go out this stuff and call firebase directly, ensuring that everything works and then go back to the redux way if you still want to use it. I also make it parallelized instead of sequentials. Hope it help, hard to find the real problem when it can come from anywhere.

```
onUploadImages = () => {
    let photo = Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? this.state.images.map(img => img.uri.replace('file://', ''))
    : this.state.images.map(img => img.uri);

    Promise.all( photo.map( image => {
        const sessionId = new Date().getTime();
        const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
        //This is kind useless
        //const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
        //This is not used
        //window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
        //This is not adviced
        //window.Blob = Blob;
        let uploadBlob = null;
        let mime = 'image/jpg';

        const imageRef = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref('brandProducts/')
        .child(`${this.props.userData.uid}`)
        .child(`${sessionId}-${i}`);

        return fs.readFile(image, 'base64')
        .then(data => {
            return RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob.build(data, {type: `${mime};BASE64`});
        })
        .then(blob => {
            uploadBlob = blob;
            return imageRef.put(blob, {contentType: mime});
        })
        .then(() => {
            uploadBlob.close();
            return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        });
    ))
    .then( results => {
        //results is, here, [ urlFromFirst, urlFronSecond, ...]
        const urls = { ...this.state.urls};
        results.forEach( (r, i) => urls[i] = r );
        const postObj = {
            ...this.state.postObj,
            urls
        };
        
        return firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('brandProducts')
        .add(postObj)
    })
    .then( docRef => {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to add a .then() to a redux action call. It was worth a shot but i received the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: This is great! Works like a charm and I much rather prefer this approach. Thank you for the assistance I appreciate it!! @farvilain